# Different styles on multiple pages

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I'm using _s to build a theme. I want to have different styles for different pages. I can figure out how to get two pages working but I want different styles for 5 pages? Maybe an else if statement? I would really appreciate some help.

here is my code.

```
 if (is_page_template('page-templates/page-about.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'sentiencesentient-layout-style' ,    get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/about.css');
    } else{
        wp_enqueue_style('sentiencesentient-layout-style' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/content-full.css');

        }
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use elseif to check another page template and you can go on like this.

```
if ( is_page_template('page-templates/page-1.php') ) {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'sentiencesentient-layout-style' ,    get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/style1.css');

} elseif ( is_page_template('page-templates/page-2.php') ) {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'sentiencesentient-layout-style' ,    get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/style2.css');

} elseif ( is_page_template('page-templates/page-3.php') ) {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'sentiencesentient-layout-style' ,    get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/style3.css');

} elseif ( is_page_template('page-templates/page-4.php') ) {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'sentiencesentient-layout-style' ,    get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/style4.css');

} else {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'sentiencesentient-layout-style' ,    get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/style5.css');
}
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thankyou for your fast reply. Have a nice day!

Comment: Cool :) have a nice weekend